# clicking button not happening anything in android

Tags: android

In my application I am displaying list view with image and text in that i added one button called read more if i click the read more button i want to move to next activity.

can any one please help.

**OurTeam class**

```
public class OurTeam extends Activity {
    Button click;

    // Array of strings storing country names
     String[] countries = new String[] {
                "Arun Arora Chairman, Edvance Group",
                "Anshul Arora CEO, Edvance Group ",
                "Ranjan Goyal CEO, Edvance Pre-Schools "

        };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
     int[] flags = new int[]{
                R.drawable.arun_arora_chairman,
                R.drawable.anshul_arora_ceo,
                R.drawable.ranjan_goyal_ceo




        };

    // Array of strings to store currencies


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ourteam1);      

       click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);

        //click.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        /*click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //click.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.voted);               
                //mp.start();       
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(in);
                //text.setText("Thanks for Voting S K Vel Election Date is on 24th April 2014. Please come and vote for your S K Vel. Our Party Symbol is Drum.");
                //text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }); */

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
            aList.add(hm);        
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.ourteam, from, to);


        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        final ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);  

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                switch (position) {
                case R.id.click:
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                      break;

                }


            }


        });


    }



}
```

**ourteam.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"    
     >

    <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"        

            />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"            
            >    

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold"            
            />   
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/click"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

                android:text="Read More" />       



        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ourteam1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where  is **findViewById()** for your click button?

Comment: button is in the listView or  outside it?

Comment: the above is my layout ourteam

Answer (score 0):

i think your using a custom adapter for ListView, then use the Button OnClick in Adapter getView()..

```
 holder.yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(context, AboutUs.class);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
         }
```

Comment: hi rajesh what is the holder

Comment: its a Holder Object , if your using holder's in Custom Adapter , for Ref have a look http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

if not use directly yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {..............}

Comment: By using single button only i want to move to different activities

Comment: then your code is fine.. you commented button onclick , just Uncomment your Button onclick..

Comment: button is included in the listview custom view right..?

Comment: button is included in the ListView custom view right..? you have to create a custom Adapter for your ListView. can u post your code

Comment: can you able to post a image of what u doing...? may i know what exactly u have to implement..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Custom Adapter.

1. Create a class and extends with BaseAdapter
2. In getView Methods you must add the Click event of that button and specific action on that button
3. Set the Listview this adapter in main Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `onItemClick` method. You can read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to understand the parameters from this method.

You need to check the position differently:

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
          int position, long arg3) {

         switch (position) {
         case 0: // For "Arun Arora Chairman, Edvance Group"
             Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);
             startActivity(in);
             break;
         case 1: // For "Anshul Arora CEO, Edvance Group "
             Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutUs.class);
             startActivity(in);
             break;
         ...
         }
}
```

If you want to launch the same Activity, you can remove the switch case.

This method will trigger the `onItemClick` even if the click is outside the button, if you want to restrict it to the button you need to create a [CustomAdapter](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown).

Comment: what is using adding button

Comment: hi giant00 if i click the readmore button i want to move to next activity this is my question

Comment: You need to follow the link in my answer and do a `CustomAdapter`. You will also find how to do it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view).

Answer (score 0):

add the following code below this line  `click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);` in your code
.

```
click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent in = new Intent(OurTeam.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

Comment: do leave comment after adding